# Is there way to quickly call the active contact on the Message app?

Tags: ios, messages

Oftentimes, in the middle of texting, I find myself wanting to call the other party instead.

However, in order to do that, I would have to scroll all the way to the top of the message history, just to get to the **CALL** button.

Is there a faster way to do this? Tapping on the contact name seems to be a logical trigger, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tap on the status bar will bring you to the top of the message. A quick way to get to the call button.

Comment: Single taps suffice.

Comment: Wow, didn't thought it was that simple. Works well! It's not intuitive though. Thank you.